# Python import from a virtual environment when run in apache

Tags: python, apache, flask

I am new in python. I am trying to deploy python code on apache server for i.e i have created flask api. So for apache i have installed XAMPP and changed my httpd.conf to execute python on apache. It works well!!  Here is code example which is working

Code working:

```
#!C:\Users\test.lab\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\myproject\python.exe
# enable debugging
print("Content-type: text/html\n")
print ("Hello Python Web Browser!! This is cool!!")
```

But when I tried to import that through 500 Error, Here is the code

```
#!C:\Users\test.lab\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\myproject\python.exe
# enable debugging
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
   return 'testing'
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```

flask is installed on my environment (myproject). When I run through command like python test.py and it works.

Comment: Are you able to see exactly what is causing the 500? I'm not able to replicate the error using the code you've posted above

Comment: I recommend Nginx.

Comment: With regards to this, I'm not sure but it might be worth posting your web server config too.

Comment: @C.Nivs These two code snippet which i have mentioned above are basically two python file called file1.py and file2.py

When I run file1.py i.e http://localhost/file1.py it returns
"Hello Python Web Browser!! This is cool!!"

However when I run file2.py i.e http://localhost/file2.py. This through error
"Server error!

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.

Error message:
End of script output before headers: test.py

Server error!
Error message: 
End of script output before headers: file2.py

Comment: @Swift its just apache with .py in handler i.e AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .py

Comment: Sorry I can't help with Apache

Answer (score 0):

Flask has it's own development web server.

Using `python myfile.py` which will work properly as a webserver (no need for apache on development).

If you still want do deploy on Apache, Flask have some info on how to do so, docs: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/deploying/mod_wsgi/

Special attention to this: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/deploying/mod_wsgi/#creating-a-wsgi-file

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer.. I am new in python. Till now i am assuming Flask server is just for development purpose. For production we must use any web server.

Regarding mod_wsgi i didn't get a way to install it on windows.

Comment: Doing a quick search, the recommended way today is using python's pip to install mod_wsgi: https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/blob/develop/win32/README.rst#running-mod_wsgi-on-windows

Hope this helps you out :)

Comment: Hi @Fabio I have already checked this out, If you will notice at overview section they have clearly mentioned that apache complied should be equal to python complied Microsoft VC. For example if my apache is complied with VC15 so python should be complied with VC15 too.. Then only i can get binary of WSGI. So i have created a support on WSGI https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/issues/402